# searching names in an array with a terminating character in java

Tags: java, arrays, search

I am trying to write a method to search an array of names; with the ability to exit the search by entering an '*' either as the first char in the entered string or by itself... the logic seems to be be escaping me. im not sure what im doing wrong. the method should return the array element number if it is found, otherwise, -1.

```
public int searchNames(String [] names) throws IOException{
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = "";
        while (line.charAt(0) != '*'){
            System.out.print("Enter a name to be searched, and an '*' to exit: ");
            line = keyboard.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i<name.length; i++){
                if (names[i].compareTo(line) == 0){return i;}
            }//end for loop
        }//end while loop

        return -1;

    }//end searchNames
```

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: My guess is he's getting a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` once he hits the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String line = "";
while (line.charAt(0) != '*'){
```

will throw a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because there is no character at index `0`.

Use

```
String line = "";
while (!line.startsWith("*"))
```

Comment: @DennisMeng `startWith()` instead?

Comment: should i have an inner and outer while loop? one to check for the * by its self, and the other to check at char(0)?

Comment: @StillLearningToCode Well, if it's by itself, it's also the first character.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
String line = "";
while(!line.startsWith("*"))
```

if you want strings starting with a "*" to cancel search.